# Unable to resolve assemblies that use Portable Class Libraries

Tags: .net-4.0, portable-class-library

I'm having a problem with assembly resolution on an end-user machine and I believe it's related to using Portable Class Libraries....

I have a .NET 4.0 application that was originally written in Visual Studio 2010. Recently we upgraded to Visual Studio 2012 and we've created a few projects that are Portable Class Libraries. I don't believe we need these features now, but we're also building a Windows 8 Store application that might benefit from these libraries.

When I compile my project, what exactly does the portable library feature do? I expect that it allows me to run it on different frameworks without modification or recompiling.

When I look at the library in <strike>reflector</strike> dotPeek it shows the Platform attribute as:

> .NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile5

And the references seem 2.0-ish:

> mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0
>
> System, Version=2.0.5.0
>
> System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0

When I run the application on this end-user's machine, I see an error in the log file:

> Could not load file or assembly, 'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0...'

Googling System.Core 2.0.5.0 seems to refer to SilverLight -- which appears to be one of the targeted frameworks.

This machine does not have Visual Studio installed, but has .NET 4.0 (4.0.3 update)

Is there something I should be doing differently to compile, something I should investigate in my dependencies or something I should be looking to install on the end-user machine? What does the 2.0.5.0 refer to?

Comment: 2.0.5.0 is the target version for PCL, it gets remapped by the framework.  Profile5 = Framework 4.0 and Store.  Long shot: Store apps require .NET 4.5.  Watch out for the Client profile of 4.0

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For .NET 4, you need an update ([KB2468871](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3556)) for Portable Class Libraries to work.  From the [KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871):

> **Feature 5**
>
> Changes to the support portable libraries. These changes include API
>   updates and binder modifications. This update enables the CLR to bind
>   successfully to portable libraries so that a single DLL can run on the
>   .NET Framework 4, on Silverlight, on Xbox, or on the Windows Phone.
>   This update adds public Silverlight APIs to the .NET Framework 4 in
>   the same location. The API signatures will remain consistent across
>   the platform. All modifications are 100 percent compatible and will
>   not break any existing code.

Also see the "Deploying A .NET Framework App" section of the [MSDN Portable Class Library Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391.aspx).

**EDIT:** Actually, if the machine has .NET 4.0.3 installed as you mention, that should be sufficient.  Can you double-check to make sure that it is actually installed?

Comment: Very strange. I downloaded http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29053 (KB2600211 published 03/04/12) but when I executed it said it was "blocked" or already installed. I downloaded KB2468871 (published 6/08/11)and was able to install without issue. The app now works.

Comment: I still get this error with both update saying "does not apply to your system".  This is with VS 2012.  Sigh.

Comment: Looks like the compiler has some glitches with the PCLs, for my issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/780023/xaml-designer-throws-nullreferenceexception-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-sometimes-for-mvvm, https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779370/vs2012-incorrectly-resolves-mscorlib-version-when-referencing-pcl-assembly

Comment: We had a machine with .NET 4.0.3 installed and still encountered this error.  Installing KB2468871 fixed it.

Comment: KB2468871 does not apply to Windows 8 or 8.1, however I'm seeing this issue during compilation of a VS project on a Windows 8.1 machine.

Comment: Still an issue... New Windows 10 machine, .NET 4.8 installed, References to System.Core.2.0.5 do not resolve - KB2468871 is blocked, all attempts to install .Net 4.0 are also blocked....

Dead in the water.