# Changing IoC provider on an Caliburn Micro WPF Application

Tags: ninject, mef, caliburn.micro

I've an existing WPF application based on caliburn micro MVVM pattern which was using Ideablade/cocktail for accessing to database. Now I've switched to servicestack and I was keeping on cocktail just for the composition pattern. Since I've noticed it takes quite a bit long to start the application I've done some test and Ninject performs better.
I find extremly usefull the MEF approach of defining the Export/ImportingConstrucor approach but and I was wondering how I can have it with Ninject... is it possible?

In my current implementation I've something as

```
[Export(typeof(IMyInterface))]
[Export(typeof(MyFirstViewModel))]
public class MyFirstViewModel:IMyInterface
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MyFirstViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)ù
    {
    }
}
```

I've seend that in ninject I've to define something as

```
 mKernel.Bind<MyFirstViewModel>().To<MyFirstViewModel>();
 mKernel.Bind<MyFirstViewModel>().To<MyFirstViewModel>();
```

Can it be automatic?
Can I also define a funct to resolve when not found?

Thanks

```
StackTrace :
 at Caliburn.Micro.IoC.<.cctor>b__0(Type service, String key) in c:\Users\Rob\Documents    \CodePlex\caliburnmicro\src\Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight\IoC.cs:line 13
 at Caliburn.Micro.IoC.Get[T](String key) in c:\Users\Rob\Documents\CodePlex\caliburnmicro\src\Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight\IoC.cs:line 32
 at myApp.Modules.Core.Framework.ViewModels.myAppScreenBase`1..ctor() in c:\Projects\myApp\branches\myApp-branch-20140526\myApp\Core\Framework\ViewModels\myAppScreenBase.cs:line 44
 at myApp.Modules.Core.Framework.ViewModels.myAppSimpleScreen`1..ctor() in c:\Projects\myApp\branches\myApp-branch-20140526\myApp\Core\Framework\ViewModels\myAppSimpleScreen.cs:line 8
 at myApp.Modules.AdE.ViewModels.CMATCLIDDelegheViewModel..ctor(IAdERepository repository, IDialogManager dialogManager, ICommonRepository commonRepository) in c:\Projects\myApp\branches\myApp-branch-20140526\myApp\Modules.AdE\ViewModels\CMATCLIDDelegheViewModel.cs:line 56
 at DynamicInjector1033b54d439c44dbaa064db1c7e82f18(Object[] )
 at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context)
 at Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object scope)
 at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
 at Ninject.KernelBase.<>c__DisplayClass15.<Resolve>b__f(IBinding binding)
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__b1`1.MoveNext()
 at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()
```

RepositoryExport :

```
public class RepositoryBindingGenerator : IBindingGenerator
{
    public IEnumerable<IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>> CreateBindings(Type type, IBindingRoot bindingRoot)
    {

        foreach (var attribute in type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RepositoryAttribute), false)
            .OfType<RepositoryAttribute>())
        {
            yield return bindingRoot
                            .Bind(attribute.ContractType ?? type)
                            .To(type).InSingletonScope();
        }


    }
}
```

but I got this compile error

Error   19  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Ninject.Syntax.IBindingNamedWithOrOnSyntax' to 'Ninject.Syntax.IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I think the exception is unrelated to Ninject, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622546/ioc-is-not-initialized-on-win7-xp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the configuration of ninject (by default its enabled) you don't need to bind a type to itself, ninject will resolve it automatically. So `mKernel.Bind<MyFirstViewModel>().To<MyFirstViewModel>();` is superfluous. Remark: Creating the binding anyway also works.

However, if you want to bind `Bar` to `IFoo` or `Foo` to `IFoo` you need to bind it.
With it you can tell ninject to look for all types with an `[Export]` attribute and bind these.
Here comes the [ninject conventions extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions) to the rescue. Get the ninject.extensions.conventions nuget package.

Then create a convention binding:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x
                .FromThisAssembly()
                .SelectAllClasses()
                .WithAttribute<ExportAttribute>()
                .BindWith<ExportBindingGenerator>());

public class ExportBindingGenerator : IBindingGenerator
{
    public IEnumerable<IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>> CreateBindings(Type type, IBindingRoot bindingRoot)
    {
        foreach (var attribute in type.GetCustomAttributes<ExportAttribute>())
        {
            yield return bindingRoot
                            .Bind(attribute.ContractType)
                            .To(type);
        }
    }
}
```

Things get a bit more complicated when you need to also use the `[ImportingConstructor]` attribute to tell ninject which constructor to use. But i would suppose that you don't need it, since Ninject's [auto-constructor-selection](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns). What you can do however is replace all `[ImportingConstructor]` attributes with Ninject's `[Inject]` attribute which does exactly the same.

Notes:

- You may need to use another method than `.FromThisAssembly()` to specify all the assemblies which contain the implementation types.
- If the implementation types are not public, you need to add `IncludeNonePublicTypes()` to the convention.

Comment: Hello BatteryBackupUnit, I've tried your solution and it partially works...partially since I forgot to tell you that in some ViewModels I have to export an ITaggable interface and the viewmodel itself, when I try to resolve the kernel.GetAll<ITaggable> I got an exception tellin IoC has not been initialized.. how can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide the exact exception? Complete message and Stacktrace.

Comment: IoC is not initialized. StackTrace :  at Caliburn.Micro.IoC.<.cctor>b__0(Type service, String key) in c:\Users\Rob\Documents\CodePlex\caliburnmicro\src\Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight\IoC.cs:line 13
   at Caliburn.Micro.IoC.Get[T](String key) in c:\Users\Rob\Documents\CodePlex\caliburnmicro\src\Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight\IoC.cs:line 32
   at myApp.Modules.Core.Framework.ViewModels.myAppScreenBase`1..ctor() in c:\Projects\myApp\branches\myApp-branch-20140526\myApp\Core\Framework\ViewModels\myAppScreenBase.cs:line 44

Comment: at myApp.Modules.Core.Framework.ViewModels.myAppSimpleScreen`1..ctor() in c:\Projects\myApp\branches\myApp-branch-20140526\myApp\Core\Framework\ViewModels\myAppSimpleScreen.cs:line 8
   at myApp.Modules.AdE.ViewModels.CMATCLIDDelegheViewModel..ctor(IAdERepository repository, IDialogManager dialogManager, ICommonRepository commonRepository) in c:\Projects\myApp\branches\myApp-branch-20140526\myApp\Modules.AdE\ViewModels\CMATCLIDDelegheViewModel.cs:line 56
   at DynamicInjector1033b54d439c44dbaa064db1c7e82f18(Object[] )
   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context)

Comment: at Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object scope)
   at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
   at Ninject.KernelBase.<>c__DisplayClass15.<Resolve>b__f(IBinding binding)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__b1`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()

Comment: please edit the original question and put the error / stacktrace there.. it's so unreadable as a comment! ;-)

Comment: I'll do right now, btw I've seen that the problem is when I do IoC.Get<myModel>(); inside the constructors

Comment: I've almost managed... I had to set the two function of ioc... GetInstance and GetAllInstances... Thanks

Comment: Excuse me again, I've seen that this way I've got my Repositories that are not singleton, I've created a CustomAttribute called RepositoryAttribute and I've decorated all my repo, I want to bind them InSingletonScope.can I do kernel.Bind(x => x
            .FromThisAssembly()
                // .IncludingNonePublicTypes()
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .WithAttribute<ExportAttribute>()
            .WithAttribute<RepositoryAttribute>()
            .BindWith<ExportBindingGenerator>()
            );

Comment: sure thing, just adjust the binding generator, add an `.InSingletonScope()` after to `.To(type)`.