# Adding managed DLL to unity3d

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine, gesture-recognition

I'm trying to implement the $p library to recognize gestures for spell casting in a game but I'm getting a Unhandled Exception. I'm using the precompile dll I got from their website and its compiled in the .Net 4 framework, so I'm guessing this is where the problem is coming from. Here is the error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (bool)

  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespace (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.GlobalRootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.LoadReferences () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

Missing method .ctor in assembly C:\Users\Uri\Desktop\GestureSpell\GestureSpell\Assets\PDollarGestureRecognizer.dll, type System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute
The class System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute could not be loaded, used in PDollarGestureRecognizer
Can't find custom attr constructor image: C:\Users\Uri\Desktop\GestureSpell\GestureSpell\Assets\PDollarGestureRecognizer.dll mtoken: 0x0a00000d
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity have you created a completely new framework 4 project and added it? Just to see if the DLL works at all?

Comment: No i have not, as I said I just dragged the dll into the project from the download I got. Are you suggesting I recompile the solution I downloaded and test that ?

Comment: No, you didn't mention you already had a solution downloaded. It looked like you only had the DLL file. Never mind.

Comment: recompiling the solution to target .Net 2 seems to have fixed it but I got a bunch of warnings that The primary reference "System.Core" could not be resolved, so I'm guessing this will break the functionality.

Comment: Have you seen this? [Load System.Core from .NET 4](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18561716/3227403)

Comment: @pid Thanks for the help, but I have to be honest here I dont really understand the link you gave me. Compiling to .Net 3.5 solved all the warnings but one and still works in unity, so I'm going to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing true to false in your .csproj file. That helps in some cases.