# FxCop 10.0 standalone failing to analyse assemblies that use AutoMapper

Tags: .net, automapper, fxcop, portable-class-library

I am having difficulty persuading FxCop 10.0 to analyse assemblies that reference AutoMapper.

I have created a simple class library, referenced AutoMapper via NuGet, and added the following code:

```
using System;

namespace ClassLibrary4
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void Foo()
        {
            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Obj1, Obj2>()
                      .ForMember(x => x.Name, opt => opt.Ignore());
        }
    }

    public class Obj1
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Obj2
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I then tried to use FxCop 10.0 to analyse the assembly via the command line, and receive the message:

> Could not load C:\Users\inelson\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ClassLibrary4\ClassLibrary4\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary4.dll.
>
> NOTE: One or more referenced assemblies could not be found. Use the '/directory' or '/reference' switch to specify additional assembly reference search paths.

**Unresolved reference is to System.Core Version 2.0.5.0**.

In an effort to isolate the issue, I removed the .ForMember method call, leaving Foo() as simply:

```
public void Foo() 
{
    AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Obj1, Obj2>(); 
}
```

and FxCop 10.0 now happily analyses the assembly!

What is it with the .ForMember method that is causing the FxCop analysis to fail?

Note that I am experiencing the same behaviour with .NET Framework versions 4.0, 4.5 or 4.5.1, and AutoMapper 3.0.0 and 3.1.0.

Comment: Long shot.. but have you tried adding a using statement for the AutoMapper extensions namespace?

Comment: Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.

Comment: @HansPassant I've tried that, no failed bindings are showing.

Comment: Not sure which namespace you mean Andy - there is no AutoMapper.Extensions namespace as far as I can see. ForMember isn't an extension method, and it is in the root AutoMapper namespace.

Comment: Please, provide output from command FxComCmd.exe /file:ClassLibrary4.dll /console /v . From your question isn't obvious which exactly assembly couldn't be found. Usually, this error looks like that: Could not load 'Library.dll'. The following error was encountered while reading module 'Library': Assembly reference cannot be resolved: 'dependencyStrongName'.

Comment: At the risk of sounding stupid, FX10 seems to be old. Does it care about lambda expressions?

Comment: Thanks @VladimirAlmaev - having run FxCop in verbose mode, I can see that the unresolved reference is to System.Core Version 2.0.5.0. I think I am experiencing the issue described in this AutoMapper GitHub thread - https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/383

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that AutoMapper.dll exists in output directory (in your case it is C:\Users\inelson\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ClassLibrary4\ClassLibrary4\bin\Debug)

**UPDATE:**
It is a well known problem with Portable Libraries and FxCop. Please, see answers:

- [FxCop indirect reference to System.Core version 2.0.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527674/fxcop-indirect-reference-to-system-core-version-2-0-5-0)
- [Unable to resolve assemblies that use Portable Class Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871267/unable-to-resolve-assemblies-that-use-portable-class-libraries)

This problem also discussed in [AutoMapper bugtracker](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/383).

**UPDATE 2:**
And I'm pretty sure that problem appears because FxCop standalone version doesn't support .NET 4.5 and Portable Class Libraries. You can vote for appropriate suggestion on [Visual Studio User Voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3243367-update-standalone-fxcop-to-support-net-4-5-and-po?page=3&per_page=20).

Did you try to run code analysis via Visual Studio?

**UPDATE 3:**
I try to run 11.0.50727.1 version of FxCopCmd.exe which installed with Visual Studio 2012 (I found it at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop) and it seems to work.

Also, I try to run Code Analysis in Visual Studio 2012 and it also works.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, I have also successfully analysed the assembly using FxCop 11 and FxCop 12. It seems these are not available as a standalone installation, I will see whether Visual Studio 2012/2013 can be installed on the build server.